# battery_state_of_charge publishes nothing on Pioneer3DX

Tags: ros, battery, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

in the rosaria documentation is written that, if the pioneer supports battery_state_of_charge the topic is published. The topic is published, but there is never any data comming. Does anyone know if the Pioneer3DX supports battery_state_of_charge ? If it supports it, what do i have to do to get the values ?

regards peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191251/battery_state_of_charge-publishes-nothing-on-pioneer3dx/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i do not use the Pioneer3DX
if have the useful points ,tell me .

---

Originally posted by [sacredsun](https://answers.ros.org/users/22715/sacredsun/) with karma: 16 on 2015-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0